# Is there a way to cause Microsoft Visual Studio to display auto-generated files differently in the edit window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I remember once while using Microsoft Visual Studio, opening a source file (by accident I think) and having it render in either subdued colors or with a different background and showing a watermark indicating that this file was not a normal editable source file.  I was under severe time pressure then and unfortunately can't recall the file or the wording of the watermark (or I would be able to investigate unaided).

Does this ring a bell with anybody?  Is there a way to cause MVS to display auto-generated files in a different manner so that the developer does not waste time editing something that should not be edited?  I open plenty of auto-generated files all the time (usually as a result of some global search) and it would be helpful to have all such files render in the editor this way.

The MVS version in question is Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015.  I have Resharper and OzCode as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having this same problem. For the files I work with (web stuff, js, css, etc.) the watermark is applied by Web Compiler: "Shows a watermark when opening a generated file" (see features list in https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler).

It turns out the "Generated" mark is toggled by clicking the bottom right corner of the editor window. In fact, it is always there, however if you accidentally click it, that will cause it to be hidden UNLESS you mouse over the bottom right corner of the editor window of the generated file.

So, to re-enable the watermark:

1. Open a file you know for sure is generated, like one of the output files in your compilerconfig.json file.
2. In the editor window, mouse over the bottom right corner of the window. You should see the "Generated" text re-appear, with a tooltip that says "Click to toggle visibility".
3. Click the text. From now on the "Generated" watermark will show up in your generated files. Just be sure not to accidentally click and hide it again.

-Michael